# java.time : DateTimeParseException for date "20150901023302166"

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

```
LocalDateTime.parse("20150901023302166", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"))
```

gives the error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20150901023302166' could not be parsed at index 0

Answer (score 11):

A workaround is to build the formatter yourself using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and fixed width for each field. This code produces the correct result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                                        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
                                        .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("20150901023302166", formatter));
}
```

So it looks like there is a problem with the formatter when building it from a pattern. After searching the OpenJDK JIRA, it seems this is indeed a bug, as referenced in [JDK-8031085](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085) and scheduled to be fixed in JDK 9.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll take that code until JDK9

Comment: Wow - I would never have expected the problem to be in constructing the formatter to start with. Nice catch :) Will remove my answer...