# LocalDateTime.parse() with a pattern only numbers

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, java-8, java-time

I want to parse a LocalDateTime from the following pattern:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss000000
```

That means the usual "yyyy...ss" and then six trailing zeros.

So, formatting works fine:

```
String p = "yyyyMMddHHmmss'000000'";
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p));
```

and but parsing:

```
String p, v;
p = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";                                    // without '000000'
v = "20160131235930";
LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p));  // it works


p = "yyyy-MMddHHmmss'000000'";                           // with '-' in between
v = "2016-0131235930000000";
LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p));  // it works


p = "yyyyMMddHHmmss'000000'";                            // with '000000' but without '-'
v = "20160131235930000000";
LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p));  // it throws Exception
```

The Exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20160131235930000000' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
...
```

I can't change the format of the input value. How can I parse it correctly? Is my pattern wrong?

Java Version: 1.8.0_60 on OSX

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug with `DateTimeFormatter` and its handling of variable width input.

Constructing the following formatter with [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) solves the problem

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
                                      .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
                                      .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
                                      .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
                                      .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                                      .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                                      .appendLiteral("000000")
                                      .toFormatter();
```

The difference is that it forces a width for the field to parse with [`appendValue(field, width)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-).

This bug sounds similar to the one mentioned [in another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896709/1743880) although it mentions milliseconds instead of literal characters in the pattern.

Comment: The only downside is you're introducing a Y10K problem :)

Comment: @bowmore Correct :D Let's hope that the bug will be resolved by then :).